# React Custom Component - Button - Call JQuery plugin on OnClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I want to add legitRipple.js to a custom React Button click event.
link to legitRipple JS: https://matthias-vogt.github.io/legitRipple.js/

Here is my draft but it is not working - I don't know how to link the click event and the reference to .ripple() event

```
Button = class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {

    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    //need to add JQuery function - on button click, I need to register an event? or somehow call (ref=buttonEl) $(buttonEl).ripple();

  }

//do I need an componentWillUnmount as well?

  onClick(ev) {
    let onClickFn = this.props.onClick;
    onClickFn && onClickFn(ev);
   //somehow register an event to show the ripple? 
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button" ref="buttonEl" className={this.props.className} onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>
          {this.props.children}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your button element using `this.refs.buttonEl`, and that should allow you to do a `$(this.refs.buttonEl).ripple()` to install the ripple handler on that element.

From the documentation, it looks like the element should automatically ripple when clicked.  Doesn't look like you have to call anything during onClick to make that happen.

You probably want to do a `$(this.refs.buttonEl).ripple({unbind: true});` in your `componentWillUnmount`.  You may also need to remove the event handler during `componentWillUpdate` and attach it during `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: Thanks so much ... that worked! I should have read the document that I didnt need to wait for a onClick event to call the jquery. 

I know this wasnt the question but if I did have to run a jquery plugin on a click event, how would I have done it above? I know Im going to run into this issue in the future

Comment: Roughly the same way.  In your onClick, you can use the same this.refs.buttonEl to get your element, then make whatever jQuery call you would in plain old JS.  Also, because you're binding in the constructor, you can just do onClick={this.onClick}